# Grep capping size of results lines, for multiple grep phrases?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I am grepping for terms like this:

```
grep 'term1\|term2\|term3\|term4'
```

and I want to say, for all lines which are found, cap the results to 100 characters. I found some examples how to do this when searching for one term, but none accommodating the OR-ing of search terms.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, wouldn't something like `grep 'term1\|term2\|term3\|term4' | cut -c1-100` do the job?

Comment: Show sample input and your desired output for that sample input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with GNU grep:

```
grep -E 'term1|term2|term3|term4' file | grep -oE '^.{100}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use awk:

```
awk '/term1|term2|term3|term4/{print substr($0,1,100)}' file
```